# Comprobar si existe un usuario y enviar a ajax un error o un succes

Tags: php, pdo

Quiero validar si un usuario existe o no a la hora de hacer un registro mediante `ajax`

Lo que intento es que en el `php`, si existe un usuario, mande un error al `ajax` en el `index.php` y si no hay un usuario, inserte los datos en la base de datos y lance un `succes`

Este es mi `Index.php`

```
<?php require_once('config/db/conexion.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="register" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass">
      <input type="submit" id="reg" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
    $('#reg').click(function(){
        var form = $('#register').serialize();
        var request;
        request = $.ajax({
            url:"ajax/register.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            type:"POST",
            data:form,
            success:function(data){
                if(!data.success){
                    swal("Oops!", data.responseText, "succes");
                }
            },
            error:function(error){
                swal("Oops!", error.responseText, "error");
            }


        });



        return false;
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el contenido de mi `ajax/register.php`

```
<?php require_once('../config/db/conexion.php'); ?>
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
if (empty($_POST['name']) && empty($_POST['pass'])) {  #Aqui comprueba si los campos estan vacios
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"); # Si esta vacio lanza un Bad Request
    echo "Los Campos estan vacios!"; # Y muestra el mensaje de error en este caso Los campos "pass" y "name" estan vacios
    return;
}else{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $stmt = $db->query("select * from users where username = '.$name.' ");
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount($stmt)>1) { #Aqui comienza la comprobasion de si existe o no el usuario
        echo "ss"; #Si existe lanza un error en este caso añadi un ss para probar                   
        return;

    } else { #Si el usuario no existe lo crea
        $username = trim($_POST['name']);
        $password = trim($_POST['pass']);
        $userid = rand(6000,9000); #Genera una id aleatoria extra usada para 
                                   #identificar al usuario en un buscador

        $incert = "INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `password`, `id_user`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$userid."');";
        $db->prepare($incert)->execute();
        echo json_encode(array("error" => false, "success" => "Correcto"));
    }
}

?>
```

Mi tabla en la base de datos

```
users-> id int(11)->username varchar(255)->password varchar(255)->id_user int(11)
```

Ahora, mi problema es que en la parte de la comprobación envía un mensaje de error y crea un usuario. Ademas, si el usuario existe, igual crea un usuario o de vez en cuando no lo crea.

Tienen idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varios errores en tu código de servidor. Básicamente, no tienes control en las salidas. Sacas `echo`, sacas encabezados de error, sacas JSON, sacas cosas diversas. Es un error. **Si la petición espera un JSON no puedes sacar cosas a mansalva, sino un único JSON**.

En el código te muestro cómo ir recogiendo en un array los datos y **sólo al final lo sacamos** en forma de JSON.

Otro error es que usas `query` combinado con `execute`. Cuando usas `query` ya obtienes los datos y `execute` se usa con consultas preparadas mediante `prepare`. **Es lo correcto aquí para evitar Inyección SQL**. Así que he escrito las consultas preparadas y pasado los datos en el `execute`.

Hay más evaluaciones, para controlar todos los posibles fallos, para eso son todos los `if`. En el código tienes siempre que prever cualquier eventualidad indicando en el objeto de respuesta que esa eventualidad ocurrió, de lo contrario habría partes no cubiertas en el código y el comportamiento podría ser cualquier cosa.

En cuanto al POST, he recogido los datos en variables para dar más claridad al código y dejar al POST tranquilo una vez evaluamos y sacamos los datos. Luego usamos las variables.

En cuano a `$mData` la lógica es poner una clave `error` en cualquiera de los errores y una clave `success` en el éxito. Luego en Ajax sólo buscas si tiene esa clave o no y la info estará dentro de la misma clave. O sea, en Ajax, si pones un `console.log(data.error)` verás el mensaje de error que pusimos en la clave `error` de `$mData` y si pones: `data.success` verás el mensaje que pusimos en la clave `success`. Para verifica si la respuesta tiene una u otra clave, bastaría con hacer `if (data.error)` o `if(data.success)` y los `if` pueden hacerse también en negativo claro está. Eso ya depende de tu lógica.

He comentado el código para que entiendas lo que se ha hecho. Si tienes dudas, comenta.

## PHP

```
<?php
    require_once('../config/db/conexion.php');
    #Variable que recoge la respuesta
    $mData=array();
    #Comprobamos si están vacíos y al mismo tiempo recogemos los datos en variables
    $name= !empty($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : NULL;
    $pass= !empty($_POST['pass']) ? trim($_POST['pass']) : NULL;
    #Comprobamos variables, trabajaremos sólo con ellas a partir de ahora
    if ($name && $pass) {
        #Escribimos una consulta preparada usando COUNT por ser más seguro
        $sql="select COUNT(*) total from users where username=?";
        #Parámetros que pasaremos a la consulta
        $params=array($name);
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        #Verificamos posibles errores de preparación y ejecución
        if ( $stmt->execute($params) ) {
            if ($stmt->fetchColumn()>1) {
                $mData["error"]="usuario existe";
                #Cerramos el recurso $stmt
                $stmt=null;
            } else {
                #Ya tenemos name y pass en las variables recogidas al principio
                $userid = rand(6000,9000);
                $insert = "INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `password`, `id_user`) VALUES (?,?,?);";
                $params=array($name,$pass,$userid);
                if ( $db->prepare($insert)->execute($params) ) {
                    $mData["success"]="Usuario $name creado";
                }else{
                    $mData["error"]="No se pudo crear el usuario. Posible clave duplicada";
                }
            }
        }else{
            $mData["error"]="Error preparando o ejecutando la consulta";
        }
    }else{
        $mData["error"]="Faltan datos en el POST";
    }
    #Salida única del código en la que $mData tendrá la información de lo que haya ocurrido
    header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($mData);
?>
```

## Javascript

Modificamos un poco el manejo del ´success`... OJO, la parte`error`es para errores de red o de servidor, no para errores de la lógica del código. O sea, la clave`error`de`$mData`sería para manejarla en el`success`también, porque el código no ha fallado. Y, en el ´success` no usas `responseText` sino las claves de `data`

```
        success:function(data){
            if(!data.success){
                //Aquí en data.error habrá el mensaje de error de $mData (servidor)
                //Y en data.success habrá el mensaje: Usuario $name creado emitido desde el servidor
                swal("Oops!", data.error, "succes");
            }
        },
```

Comment: me lanza este error Undefined variable: stmt y Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on null en la linea 15

Comment: @Max prueba de definir `$stmt` primero y luego haces el `if`. Cambia la línea 15 por esto: `$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
  if ( $stmt && $stmt->execute($params) ) {` primero defines la variable y luego el `if`

Comment: al parecer si lo añado asi me deja de fallar ``$stmt = $db->prepare($sql) || $stmt->execute($params)`` pero despues me da error en ``$stmt->fetchColumn()>0`` pero probare como tu me dices

Comment: Con `OR` que es lo mismo que `||` no vale. La idea es verificar que la consulta se preparó y ejecutó sin problemas con `&&` Y verifica que es PDO realmente lo que traes al incluir la conexión.

Comment: usando como tu me dijiste me lanza este error `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''ss''  `

Comment: Ok @Max, hay un error de sintaxis en esta consulta: `select COUNT(*) total from users where username ?`, tienes que ponerla así: **`select COUNT(*) total from users where username=?`** me faltó el signo de `=`

Comment: bueno no me da mas el error de Syntax pero ahora me da un error en ``Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean linea 17``

Comment: @Max parece que el  `$stmt` no está devolviendo recursos, sino que es `false` pero en ese caso no debería pasar el `if`. ¿Podrías ponerme cómo tienes esa parte, desde la creación de `$stmt` hasta el uso de `fetchColumn`?  Debe haber algo erróneo ahí.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103154/discussion-between-max-and-a-cedano).